# Возможно ли вывести текст после input() Python?

Tags: python, input, print

Вывод:

```
Some_text1
Some_text2

> input - Здесь пользователь вводит что-нибудь

Some_text3
Some_text4
```

*Выводить текст после input(), но пока пользователь не нажал enter

Проблема:

Если вызвать input(), то программа ждет пока пользователь не нажмет энтер, и собственно последующие принты будут ждать.

А если запускать в отдельном потоке принтинг, то указатель, или как это, курсор, будет всегда спускаться в конец, даже после вывода текста.

Comment: И в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Ну, если вызвать input(), от программа ждет пока пользователь не нажмет энтер, и собственно последующие принты будут ждать.
А если запускать в отдельном потоке принтинг, то указатель, или как это, курсор, будет всегда спускаться в конец, даже после вывода текста

Comment: Были тут подобные вопросы. Там поток по-моему советовали запускать, чтобы он что-то писал

Comment: Библиотеку curses не пробовали?

Comment: У меня с курсесом немного другие проблемы, вот и хотел поинтересоваться, можно ли то реализовать безе него.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот код

```
from threading import Thread

class InputThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            s = input('Введите строку: ')
            print(s)


class PrintThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('Me work!')
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    it = InputThread().start()
    pt = PrintThread().start()
```

Comment: Кажется, что при таких двух потоках главный простаивает - это намеренно, или можно вместо одного из потоков использовать главный?

Comment: Даже если пользователь всё еще не нажал энтер, т.е. вводит в инпут, то текст выводимый другим потоком, будет отсылать написанный пользователем текст и курсор в конец.

Answer (score -1):

```
print("Some text here")
print("Some text here")
inp = input()
print(inp)
print("Some text here")
```

Comment: Не выводить текст, что ввел пользователь, а выводить текст после курсора, пока пользователь еще вводит